# Android WAKE_LOCK permission rights

Tags: android, android-c2dm, android-wake-lock

I use a wake lock `pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, C2DM);` in implementation of the C2DM service, and I use a `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` permission in AndroidManifest. I was interested, what rights does the wake lock actually have? I know that it is not release in application's onPause() and onStop(), it can turn on the screen when new message comes.
But what else? How much battery it uses? If the device is turned off, then the c2dm message won't wake it up, right, so the wake lock is released when the device is turned off? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More 3 rights (could be more...)
1. Keep the RIL (Radio Interface Layer) on so your app could get notifications from it (like RSSI level and so)
2. Keep the cpu on for your app so it could get other notifications like location updates.
3. There is an option to keep the screen on (for instance, when you play a video).